# How to call a scalar function in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am wacking my head over the problem with this code.

```
DECLARE @root hierarchyid
DECLARE @lastchild hierarchyid
SELECT @root = NodeHierarchyID FROM NodeHierarchy WHERE ID = 1
SET @lastchild = getlastchild(@root)
```

It says it does not recognize `getlastchild` function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

try including the schema id, as in

```
@lastchild = dbo.getlastchild(@root)
```

Comment: +1 you **CAN'T** call a user defined function in SQL Server 2008 without using the schema

Comment: but, don't forget the "SET", e.g., `SET @lastchild = ...`

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
set @lastchild = dbo.getlastchild(@root)
```

From [CREATE FUNCTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258261(SQL.80).aspx)

> Scalar-valued functions may be invoked
>   where scalar expressions are used,
>   including computed columns and CHECK
>   constraint definitions. **When
>   invoking scalar-valued functions, at
>   minimum use the two-part name of the
>   function.**

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
set @lastchild = dbo.getlastchild(@root)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.function(@parameters)
```