# Executing one stored-procedure from another throws error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

My Stored procedure is like this

```
       SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    create  PROCEDURE ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp
        @Year INT,
        @strYear VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT
    AS

    IF NULLIF(@Year, '') IS NULL
        SET @Year = Exec [cs_GetCurrentYear]  @strYear 
    SELECT DISTINCT [VolID], [CampID], [VolFName] FROM [vStaffJobAndCamp]
 where  CampCode Like @Year
```

As you can see I am trying to execute `[cs_GetCurrentYear]` inside this procedure (added the procedure below)

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cs_GetCurrentYear]
    @strYear VARCHAR(2) OUTPUT
AS
    SELECT @strYear = Year FROM tblCurrentYear
```

But this throws an error on compile .
And it looks like this

```
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ph_GetAllStaffAddressByCamp, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Exec'.
```

Comment: Have you checked this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170328/executing-a-stored-procedure-within-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a table, and insert into it the result of your SP. Try

```
DECLARE  @TheYear TABLE
(

TheYear Varchar(2)

)

 INSERT INTO @theYear (TheYear)
  Exec [cs_GetCurrentYear]  @strYear 

   SET @Year = (SELECT TOP(1) TheYear FROM  @TheYear)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your second stored procedure to a stored function and call it from your first stored procedure. Read more here: [How to call a scalar function in a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677051/how-to-call-a-scalar-function-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: I can't do that. According to specific requirements in my project. Is there no way to call a storedprocedure here?

Comment: You might want to read this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter) then